# An algorithm for calculating natural number x,y,z values

Tags: polynomials

How to make an algorithm for the following problem? Explanations would be appreciated.

> Given natural number m. Create an algorithm with which you can set all three natural number x, y and z values, which satisfies the following conditions:
>   $m=x^3+y^3+z^3$

Comment: How large is $m$? Even a brute-force algorithm of checking with all $x,y,z \leq m^{1/3}$ is $O(m)$. Do you need something faster than that?

Comment: m can be any natural number

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong wit simply doing

for ($x=1$, $x^3<m$, $x++$) for ($y=1$, $x^3+y^3<m$, $y++$) for ($z=1$, $x^3+y^3+z^3\le m$, $z++$) if ($x^3+y^3+z^3==m$) print($x$, $y$, $z$)

Comment: You can further require $y\leq x$ and $z\leq y$ in the second and third if clause to speed that up.